# Can objects share other objects?

Tags: python

I was reading an article and came across:

> If a mutable object *m* is shared by two other objects *x* and
>       *y*, then a modification to *m* made via *x* wil be visible when
>       *m* is examined via *y*.

How can an object be shared by other objects and what does it mean? Would appreciate it if explained in depth, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following example. Say we have a class `Foo` that contains a `list`.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
```

We can instantiate one instance of `Foo` called `a`

```
a = Foo([1,2,3])
print(a.data)     # Outputs [1, 2, 3]
```

If we then make another instance of `Foo` called `b`, that shares the same `list` as `a`, we can see what happens when we mutate the `list`. Both objects reflect that the `list` has changed, because they both have references to the same `list`.

```
b = Foo(a.data)
b.data.append(4)
print(a.data)     # Outputs [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(b.data)     # Outputs [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Yes I understand, that b references the object a also references, but wouldn’t it be considered as one object?

Comment: What is "it" in your question? The object `a.data` is the same object as `b.data` but the objects `a` and `b` are *not* the same object as each other.

Comment: Okay I understood, is that what the author meant by “object x and object y”? "it" is the object a.data and b.data reference.

Comment: Using the author's terminology, in this example `m == data`, `a == x` and `b == y`, if that helps clear it up

Comment: Thanks! But I don’t get this, “b = Foo(a.data)” why doesn’t “b” have the same memory address as “Foo(a.data)”, I thought assignment never copies data. I’m a newbie sorry if I’m asking a lot, this is my second day with python.